# Add two variables such that they become a String with a space between in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So i am trying to output in the same line two string variables with a space but I am getting the following error:

> in `+': no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String (TypeError)

for the following code

```
puts s1 + " " + s2
```

How can I fix this code to print the value of string variable s1 with a space and the value of string variable s2 on the same line? for example

```
s1 = "hello" s2="world"  output "Hello world"
```

Comment: Ruby is not JavaScript. `+` is a method, not an operator.

Comment: @CodeGnome, some might say it is both. I've looked in vain for a definition of an "operator" in Ruby docs. Do you (or anyone else, dear readers) know of one?

Comment: @CarySwoveland: I'd probably say that `+` is an operator that is implemented as a method but it is still an operator. The existence of "Ruby has the basic set of operators (+, -, *, /, and so on) as well as a few surprises. A complete list of the operators, and their precedences, is given in Table 18.4 on page 219." in the original Ruby book and [Table 18.4: Ruby operators"](http://phrogz.net/programmingruby/language.html#table_18.4) sort of supports that.

Comment: You have not shown s1 and s2 to be initialized. Otherwise, your code is fine. `s1 = "hello"; s2= "world"; puts s1 + " " + s2` prints `"hello world"`. The error message suggests that you may be initializing s2 to an integer, not a string.

Comment: @CarySwoveland *tUPLUS* is a token for a unary plus, but `1.+ 2 #=> 3` and `"foo".+ "bar" #=> "foobar"`.  I think it's a mistake to let people new to the language think of `+` as an operator, but you can comb [parse.y](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/parse.y) and make your own decisions.

Comment: @muistooshort In support of your viewpoint, the text reads: "Expressions may be combined using operators...the operators with a Y in the method column are implemented as methods, and may be overridden." On the other hand, for String and Fixnum the operators *are* overridden as methods, and there's no way for the OP to "combine the expressions" using a unary plus. I can't think of a single pragmatic example where thinking of `+` as an operator will help someone reason about String or Numeric objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with the following:

```
puts "#{s1} #{s2}"
```

and:

```
puts [s1, s2].join(" ")
```

Here are the following examples implemented code snippets above:

```
s1, s2 = "hello", "world"
puts "#{s1} #{s2}"
=> "hello world"

puts [s1, s2].join(" ")
=> "hello world"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

`puts s1.to_s + " " + s2.to_s`

It looks like at least one of your variables contains a numerical value (int)